# Layout and rotating a shape

Tags: draw2d-js

Is it possible, to rotate a shape inside another shape with CenterLocator?

```
var shelvingCode = new draw2d.shape.basic.Label({ text: '1.01' });
myShape.add(this.shelvingCode, new draw2d.layout.locator.CenterLocator());
```

I tried to use the special command for it.

```
new draw2d.command.CommandRotate(shelvingCode , (shelvingCode .getRotationAngle() + 90) % 360);
```

But it seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I found this when I was searching to do the same thing and think I figured it out. Thought I might help out anybody else who finds this looking for the same answer :)

If I understand correctly, you wanted to have the label rotated inside another shape. To do this where you want it rotated 90 degrees more than it is now, you could do

```
shelvingCode.rotationAngle = (shelvingCode.getRotationAngle() + 90) % 360;
```

If you're rotating the label once it's already attached to the parent node, you'll need to put

```
shelvingCode.repaint();
```

so that it updates on the screen.

Comment: yeah, that was exaclty I wanted. Better later then never!